# Foursquare venue check-in authorization error

Tags: php, oauth, foursquare

I'm trying to display a list of check-ins in a venue using the following address:

https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/VENUE_ID/stats?oauth_token=OAUTH_TOKEN

I've registered Foursquare application and specified my website's URL as redirect url.
I got my client credentials and followed the instructions at https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/auth to create my code and access_token.

However, when trying to access these stats my web browser I'm getting an error:

```
{
  "meta":
  {
    "code":403,
    "errorType":"not_authorized",
    "errorDetail":"User is not authorized to view venue stats"
  },
  "response":{}
}
```

Querying venues/VENUE_ID without stats works fine and returns venue info so I assume that error must be with the OAuth token.

I am not an owner of the venue I'm trying to query.

How could I resolve the issue? May I ask venue owner for application credentials? Or is something wrong with my callback URL? Or should I run the query from the server, not through web browser?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know you cannot get the stats off any OAuth toekn, you must be identified as the owner of the venue. See the [Merchant Platform](https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/merchants) docs.

<strike>Someone should really tell foursquare to fix the [stats](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/stats) docs. (and any other that require a special token..)</strike>
They have it now at the [stats](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/stats) docs

Comment: i've been crunching to find out the reason of this error too! +1 documentation is misleading sometimes!

Comment: @jonathan-levison what kind of special token is required?

Comment: You need to have Foursquare enable (?) you the Merchant Platform. I am not really sure how it works, I guess you do not *have* to be the venue owner/manager, but you probably need some sort of authorization from him - you should send foursquare a mail and ask about it.

Answer (score 0):

I am using instead this call: https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/VENUE_ID/herenow

As per: https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/herenow

You can specify limit, offset, afterTimestamp.

Would be nice to have fromTimestamp - toTimestamp options there as the venues stats option.